# regex to find numbers in string that starts with 08 and are between 10-13 char

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to parse a string that contain strings that are 9-11 characters long and are integers and starts with 08 or +62. How do I do this in PHP? Here's my regex thus far:

```
/^(\+?62|08)[0-9]{9,11}$/
```

so here's some sample string/integer I should be able to extract out of a long string

```
082298744807
087884962429
087783218768
0818809692
081224505277
+628129191929
+62812123929
```

Comment: Have you tested you regex?

Comment: Hint: How many of the numerals do you already know about?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear if you want to match numbers between 10-13 digits, or 9-11. In any case it's a simple fix (just count the initial two digits 08, or 62 as part of the total sum of digits. To implement this in php use `preg_match_all`:

```
$pat = "/^(?:\+?62|08)[0-9]{8,11}$/uim"; // note modfied range of digits

preg_match_all($pat, $str, $res);
print_r($res[0]);
```

Example:

**http://ideone.com/GJYK7C**

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 082298744807
    [1] => 087884962429
    [2] => 087783218768
    [3] => 0818809692
    [4] => 081224505277
    [5] => +628129191929
    [6] => +62812123929
    [7] => +629490029944
)
```